# Prevent button click from activating form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a form A that is partially overlayed by another form B, both separate applications/processes.

Clicking on a specific button on form A should not cause form A to get focus/activate (keeping form B in the foreground), while clicking anywhere else on form A should bring it to the front/activate it as you would expect.

Any hints on how to achieve this are appreciated.

Comment: Since it's another application, I'm assuming you can't alter form B. Does it matter which application has focus before the button is clicked? e.g., notepad has focus and the button is clicked, should notepad get focus back or does nothing have to happen. Or is it ok if after clicking the button, from A always tries to find form B and bring it to front? (That would be easiest, you can find the process and use an api to bring its main handle to front)

Comment: Both applications are in our control, but form/window B is in Java. Actually the button needs to control the z-order of form B. When not at the top, clicking it should bring form B to the top. That's the easy bit. But when already at the top, clicking the button should bring form A to the front. But since that activates form A as well, there's no more knowing where form B was just before the click, so we don't know what action to perform (form B could also be manually brought to front/back as well).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to "prevent activation for a single button". You can, however, do the opposite.

On your form, set the `NOACTIVATE` style:

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
   get
   {
      var createParams = base.CreateParams;
      createParams.ExStyle = 0x08000000;
      return createParams;
   }
}
```

This will prevent activation when your button is clicked. You need to activate manually for everything else though (using `form.Activate()`).

Not sure there's a way to do the opposite

Answer (score 0):

The way I would handle this is by having a bool to hold whether or not FormB is on top or not and if it should be call FormB.Focus();

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 if(FormB.OnTop)
 {
  FormB.OnTop = false;
  this.Focus();
 }
 else
 {
  FormB.OnTop = true;
  FormB.Focus();
 }
}
```

Then in the design mode create an event when FormA gains focus calling

```
FormB.OnTop = false;
```